# addition of sint64 and uint32 data type result in sint64

Tags: c, autosar

when i goint to implement addition of sitn64 and uint32 the result should be return as in sint64 type in AUTOSAR_SWS_EFXLibrary. 
but some condition are given e.g

```
[SWS_Efx_00415] 
**C operators shall not be used for 64bit data (cast, arithmetic operators and comparison operators)** 
[SWS_Efx_00416] ⌈
**64bit constants shall not be used.** 
[SWS_Efx_00417]
**Direct affectation to and from a 64 bit type shall only be used through predefined functions of 64 bits library.**
[SWS_Efx_00418] ⌈
**Only the sint64 type is allowed (uint64 shall not be used)**. ⌋ ( )
[SWS_Efx_00419] ⌈
**64bit functions do not perform saturation, even for the conversion to smaller types.**
```

So How can we implement function without using c operators.

Comment: Decompose them into 32-bit ints and construct the higher-precision operations out of 32-bit operations.  The rest is up to you.

Comment: Please clarify your question, post a [mcve]. What you are mentioning will happen in C due to rules of integer promotion. If your specific coding style rules prevent 64-bit numbers, you will have to do this manually. Which is usually a worse option than letting the compiler do it for you, using functions which has been thoroughly tested.

Comment: To begin with: why do you need 64 bit arithmetic in the first place?

Comment: As it is given in autosar math library, one of the function is Efx_Add_s64s32_s64 , so what I do is                                                                                                  
     sint64 result;  result = (sint64)x +(sint64)y. but as per autosar specification they said we should not use c operator during implementation. so what is other way to implement .